# Python - How to get genre of a book from its ISBN?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dataset

I am working with - [Institut für Informatik, Universität Freiburg - Book Ratings Data Set](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/) and need the genre or category of the book from its ISBN. Is there a way to do this via an already available API (preferably in python) or do I need to perform some scraping?

Comment: You need to perform some research? What have you found so far, and why did they not reach up to your requirements? https://www.programmableweb.com/api/isbn-db

Comment: Yes, I have done some research but couldn't find an API that serves the purpose. I found a website that gives you the genre from ISBN but I had to scrape the genre from it. Since the number of books are a lot, I figured I wouldn't be allowed to make so many requests.

Comment: Have you checked out the google books API? I'm not sure about the limit, but there is a search option on ISBN number and many other (advanced) query/filtering options. https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using (About increasing requests limit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-java-client/_TFuPpAKSew)

Comment: Given that the ISBN contains country, publisher, running number (arbitrarily defined by publisher) and checksum this would require a common systematic across publishers, or the complete knowledge about the categories published by very small companies (2 to 3 digits). I guess, it's infeasible.

Comment: @guidot I guess its true. I was thinking of using that knowledge to make better recommendations to the user.